# Exporting excel for multiple dynamic kendo grids in Angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am developing a web page which contains multiple Kendo grid components based on user input. My requirement is to export all these grids to excel report. I implemented Kendo-grid excel export for each grid and it is working as expected but to bring a common export button for all these dynamic grids how can i proceed. I am using angular 2 to implement this feature. Can I use a common reference variable for all these grids? please suggest.

Comment: How you expect this to function client side is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the answer to this question. It will help you combine all the worksheets from multiple sources - [Kendo UI for Angular 2: Excel export having multiple worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890711/kendo-ui-for-angular-2-excel-export-having-multiple-worksheets)

If you like to manipulate the worksheets yourself, please see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cf4EnUL4a5LVsfvkf1aA?p=preview)
wrote by me. It shows how you can add rows(Either as header or data) - As of this writing, this is not documented.

Relevant Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { products } from './products';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <button type="button" class="k-button" (click)="save(excelexport)">Export To Excel</button>

        <kendo-excelexport #excelexport [data]="data" [fileName]=downloadFileName>
            <kendo-excelexport-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" [width]="75">
            </kendo-excelexport-column>
            <kendo-excelexport-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
            </kendo-excelexport-column>
            <kendo-excelexport-column field="SomeDate" title="Start Date" [cellOptions]="{ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' }"></kendo-excelexport-column>
      </kendo-excelexport>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public data: any[] = products;
    public downloadFileName: string = "Report - Rates.xlsx"

    public save(component): void {
        const options = component.workbookOptions();

        options.sheets[0].name = `Rate Card Report`;

        let rows = options.sheets[0].rows;
        let infoRows = [
          { cells: [{value: "12345"}], type: 'data', xyz: 1 },
          { cells: [{value: "My stuff LLC"}], type: 'data', xyz: 1 },
          { cells: [{value: "2 Fun Street"}], type: 'data', xyz: 1 },
          { cells: [{value: "Rye, NY - 10580"}], type: 'data', xyz: 1 },
          ];

        Array.prototype.unshift.apply(rows, infoRows);
        console.log(rows);

        component.save(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank this work for me perfectly for my requirements. You saved my lot of time Thanks once again.